# Java game involving adjacent JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm making a small game involving a grid of JButtons (MxN) and the main premise is to click on `buttonA` and then on `buttonB`, coloring `buttonB` and adjacent buttons of the same color as `buttonB` with the color of `buttonA`. I have made it so you are able to choose 3 possible difficulties. The colors are randomly generated. The main problem is getting the colors to change.

This is the method that I call after selecting the difficulty of the game:

```
 public static void gameMechanics(int m, int n) {
    final String[] pickedColour = {""};
    final String[] placedColour = {""};
    JButton[][] picked = new JButton[m][n];
    JButton[][] placed = new JButton[m][n];
    picked[m][n].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pickedColour[0] = picked[m][n].getText();
        }
    });
    placed[m][n].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            placedColour[0] = placed[m][n].getText();
        }
    });
    if (pickedColour[0] == "R" && placedColour[0] != "R") {
        placed[m][n].setBackground(Color.RED);
        placed[m][n].setText("R");
    }
    else if (pickedColour[0] == "G" && placedColour[0] != "G") {
        placed[m][n].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        placed[m][n].setText("G");
    }
    else if (pickedColour[0] == "B" && placedColour[0] != "B") {
        placed[m][n].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        placed[m][n].setText("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre]

Comment: Do not compare Strings using `==` and `!=`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using `JPanel`s and painting them, using a `MouseListener` instead.

However, if you're set on using JButtons, try this:

```
button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
button.setOpaque(true);
```

Note that *this might not work* if you're setting the look and feel using `UIManager`.

Also, you're doing a ton of extra work to map the color to the button - it could get confusing and cause errors down the road. Instead, you might try creating your own class:

```
class ColoredButton extends JButton {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3040767030924461426L;

        private Color color;

        public ColoredButton(Color c) {
            this.color = c;

            this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    changeColor();
                }
            });
        }

        public void changeColor() {
            this.setBackground(this.color);
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }
    }
```

Now, you can construct a new ColoredButton:

```
// Now, this button will turn green when clicked
ColoredButton temp = new ColoredButton(Color.GREEN);
```